# Compile error gcc -lpthread position

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, linker, position

This work:

```
    gcc a.o b.o -o a -lpthread
```

This does not work:

```
    gcc -lpthread a.o b.o -o a
```

and shows some errors like this:

```
undefined reference to `pthread_create'
```

So when I compile using Makefile, it generate

```
    gcc -lpthread a.o b.o -o a
```

Which does not work.

Any ideas?

P.S: I am using gcc 4.6.3/Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you want to use `-pthread`, not `-lpthread`, when compiling with pthread - `-pthread` may enable some compile-time options that are required for the program to work in multhithreaded environment.

The problem isn't really with your command line - it's a problem with GNU `ld`. GNU `ld`, upon encountering an `-lXXX` option, reads all the symbols defined by `libXXX.so` or `libXXX.a`, checks if any of those symbols have been mentioned in files *that have been specified before the `-lXXX` option in the command line*, and forgets about the rest of the symbols.

In other words: command line order of object files and libraries changes behavior of the linker.

This might've been reasonable back when computers had really limited memory, but nowadays it's just a silly artifact from long forgotten times, that should've been already fixed some time ago.

Of course, there might arise a problem of linking with several libraries defining the same symbol, but there certainly are saner ways to allow expected behavior for such cases.

---

Bottom line: for GNU `ld` (which is called by `gcc`), only the first command from your question is valid, because `ld` still lives in the previous computing era.

For extra sanity, use `-pthread` both when linking *and* compiling your pthread-related programs.

Comment: Thank man. After changing to -pthread it works regardless of the option possition.

Comment: I guess that `-pthread` adds a special case for linking it. Which proves my point that option order is not good anymore nowadays.